# Google Sheet API batchGet unable to parse range with Integromat

Tags: google-sheets-api, make.com

I am trying to use the batchGet method of Google Sheets found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221cQXS1sjsSm2utiaitcIo8twGUXGNdXHCXhraYEkASjs%22%2C%22ranges%22%3A%5B%22Personal%20Financials!c27%22%2C%22Personal%20Financials!c29%22%5D%7D).  The ranges and sheetID work fine when I am using the "Try this API" feature.  The problem is Integromat requires me to form the URL manually, it's not clear how that's done.

I am trying:
`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{my sheet ID}/values:batchGet?ranges=[sheet1!a1:a2,sheet1!b1:b2]`

I keep getting the error:

> "400: INVALID_ARGUMENT - Unable to parse range:  "

Integromat is supposed to automatically replace special characters with their % form so I don't think it's that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead,

```
/v4/spreadsheets/1MiLOwcEImnih0svZBrGwMQZ3xi3vSchhNWPiPA8Tcz0/values:batchGet?ranges=Availability!a1%3Aa2&ranges=Availability!b1%3Ab2
```

Instead of using,`ranges=[sheet1!a1:a2,sheet1!b1:b2]` it should be,

```
ranges=sheet1!a1:a2 & ranges=sheet1!b1:b2
```

Of course with URL encoding, which should be handled by Integromat.

Comment: life saver, thank you so much @Runcorn.  the issue was that I needed to send each range as a new range query param as you pointed out.

Comment: For future reference, You can always use the Google Sheet API Explorer and Try it Out feature to see what the request looks like.